# How to Display title for uitabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have created uitabbarview controller using the below code

In the uitabbar controller i want to display tile for every view

Please let me know how to add title for each view ( tab bar item )

```
myTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    MyDialerViewController *aDialerViewController = [[MyDialerViewController alloc]init];
    MyCallLogViewController *aCallLogViewController = [[MyCallLogViewController alloc] init];
    TemplateViewController *aTemplateViewController = [[TemplateViewController alloc] init];    


    NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:aDialerViewController, aCallLogViewController, aTemplateViewController, nil];
    myTabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
    myTabBarController.delegate = self;
    myTabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

    [controllers release];
    [aDialerViewController release];
    [aCallLogViewController release];
    [aTemplateViewController release];

    [self.window addSubview:myTabBarController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the title of the navcontroller directly in the appDelegate.

```
aDialerViewController.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Dialer Title", @"Dialer Title");
aCallLogViewController.title = @"Title";
aTemplateViewController.title = @"Title";
```

I'd also set it in the viewDidLoad method of those viewControllers.

Works fine for me. Remember to localize, just incase you need it in the future. (if not intended to, you should look into it)

Answer (score 0):

```
self.viewcontroller.tabBarItem = // a UITabBarItem instance
```

*Make an instance of UITabBarItem*

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITabBarItem

> - (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title image:(UIImage *)image tag:(NSInteger)tag

You could write that in the initializer function of each viewcontroller.